# How to add a condition to a for loop in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I know that in Java, it is possible to do the following:

```
boolean condition = true;

for(int i=0; i<array.length && condition; i++){

}
```

If the condition is false, the for loop stops,
but, how to do the same in Kotlin?

Comment: There are no counter-based `for` loops in Kotlin. Just use `while` loop instead.

Comment: Have you consulted the documentation? https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html, https://kotlinlang.org/docs/returns.html

Comment: What is that you need to do? Maybe there's a more idiomatic way to do it. E.g. `array.takeWhile { condition }.forEach {  }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the below approach for the conditional `for` loop.

```
(0..array.length).takeWhile {
    condition
}.forEach {
    // do something with `it (index)`
}
```

Comment: That should be `(0..<array.length)`, otherwise you'll get an IndexOutOfBoundsException for index = array.length. Better still, use `array.indices`.

Answer (score 1):

there is no such option in Kotlin (availabe constructions in [HERE](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#for-loops)), but you can add additional check and `break` keyword

```
for (i in 0..array.length) {
    if (!condition) break; // quit loop without further iteration
    //rest of code
```

Comment: `for (i in 0..<array.length)`

Answer (score 0):

```
fun checkCondition(){
  val condition=true
  outerloop@for(i in array.indices) {
    if(array[i]!=condition){
      condition=false
      break@outerloop
    }
  }
  return condition
}
```